# Type casting many variables in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Possibly wrong terminologies here, please correct me.

Problem:
I have many objects, say lists of integers `a=[1,3,7]`, `b=[1,9]`, `c...` etc. I want to convert each to an `np.array` for instance.

So far:
What works: Explicitly convert individually:

```
a=np.array(a)
b=np.array(b)
...
```

What did not work:
`[np.array(x) for x in [a,b,c...]]`
which only gives a list of the arrays (ok, that was expected) but does not change the **variable a,b...** to be of type `np.array`.

I am aware this unveils how little I know about python basics (what is pointer, what is reference etc...too long ago where I learned about it for c++).

Comment: `a,b,c = [np.array(x) for x in [a,b,c...]][np.array(x) for x in [a,b,c]]`  (but i second chepners comment)

Comment: Obligatory reading: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html. You probably don't want individual *names* in the first place, but a `dict` whose keys you can iterate over in order to reassign to the same keys. `for k, v in d.items(): d[k] = np.array(v)`.

Comment: Type casting, in the sense of changing the type of an object, does not generally work in Python. In some cases you can change the ``.__class__`` of an object, but that won't work between lists and arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You have the right idea, but as you've seen, `np.array(x)` will create a new array based on `x`, not modify `x` itself. Having said that, you can assign these values back to the original variables:

```py
a,b,c,etc=[np.array(x) for x in [a,b,c,etc]]
```